# Get values in XML nodes using SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I have an XML in SQL table column. I need to decode this xml and get value of particular nodes. Find my XML below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope
    xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <SOAP-ENV:Header/>
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <ns:createTransactionResponse
            xmlns:impl="http://office/work/services/service1"
            xmlns:ns="http://www.regfrez.com/schemas/service1_V2/SharedResources/XMLSchema/Schema.xsd"
            xmlns:tns="http://www.erdeftq.ae/Activematrix/ESB/service1/1_0">
            <transactionResponse>
                <transaction-info>
                    <registrationId>R1234</registrationId>
                    <trialId>T12345</trialId>
                    <transactionId>12345</transactionId>
                    <transactionDate>27-02-2020:08:47</transactionDate>
                    <status>Confirmed</status>
                </transaction-info>
            </transactionResponse>
        </ns:createTransactionResponse>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

I need the values of nodes: registrationId, transactionId and status and I tried this but couldn't succeed as i got empty value as result:

```
DECLARE @xml XML
SET @xml = 'XML here'
SELECT T.C.value('@status', 'nvarchar(100)') FROM @xml.nodes('createTransactionResponse/transactionResponse/transaction-info/status') T(C)
SELECT T.C.value('@trans', 'nvarchar(100)') FROM @xml.nodes('createTransactionResponse/transactionResponse/transaction-info/transactionId') T(C)
SELECT T.C.value('@id', 'nvarchar(100)') FROM @xml.nodes('createTransactionResponse/transactionResponse/transaction-info/registrationId') T(C)
```

Any help/correction would be appreciated

Comment: Ideally, you should have editted your previous question and waited for it to be reopened, however, you have now shown your attempts, which is great.

Comment: @Larnu Please suggest the resolution, if you have some info.

Comment: I'm already writing you an answer. :)

Comment: Any other way around rather than using XML type? I need w.r.to NVARCHAR datatype since this xml is stored in column of type NVARCHAR(MAX)

Comment: If you're not storing XML data as `xml` you can't treat it as XML, it's as simple as that. Fix the data type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your own attempt is ignoring the namespaces and does not specify the full XPath.

Try one of these approaches:

Your XML:

```
DECLARE @xml XML
SET @xml = '<SOAP-ENV:Envelope
    xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <SOAP-ENV:Header/>
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <ns:createTransactionResponse
            xmlns:impl="http://office/work/services/service1"
            xmlns:ns="http://www.regfrez.com/schemas/service1_V2/SharedResources/XMLSchema/Schema.xsd"
            xmlns:tns="http://www.erdeftq.ae/Activematrix/ESB/service1/1_0">
            <transactionResponse>
                <transaction-info>
                    <registrationId>R1234</registrationId>
                    <trialId>T12345</trialId>
                    <transactionId>12345</transactionId>
                    <transactionDate>27-02-2020:08:47</transactionDate>
                    <status>Confirmed</status>
                </transaction-info>
            </transactionResponse>
        </ns:createTransactionResponse>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>';
```

--This is the most explicit (which is always a *best way*):

```
WITH XMLNAMESPACES('http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/' AS n1
                  ,'http://www.regfrez.com/schemas/service1_V2/SharedResources/XMLSchema/Schema.xsd' AS n2)
SELECT @xml.value('(/n1:Envelope/n1:Body/n2:createTransactionResponse/transactionResponse/transaction-info/registrationId/text())[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS RegistrationId
      ,@xml.value('(/n1:Envelope/n1:Body/n2:createTransactionResponse/transactionResponse/transaction-info/transactionId/text())[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS TransactionId
      ,@xml.value('(/n1:Envelope/n1:Body/n2:createTransactionResponse/transactionResponse/transaction-info/status/text())[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS [Status];
```

--This will avoid some repeated XPath, but `.nodes()` produces quite some overhead:

```
WITH XMLNAMESPACES('http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/' AS n1
                  ,'http://www.regfrez.com/schemas/service1_V2/SharedResources/XMLSchema/Schema.xsd' AS n2)
SELECT ti.value('(registrationId/text())[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS RegistrationId
      ,ti.value('(transactionId/text())[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS TransactionId
      ,ti.value('(status/text())[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS [Status]
FROM @xml.nodes('/n1:Envelope/n1:Body/n2:createTransactionResponse/transactionResponse/transaction-info') A(ti);
```

--And this is for lazy people :-)

```
SELECT @xml.value('(//*:registrationId)[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS RegistrationId
      ,@xml.value('(//*:transactionId)[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS TransactionId
      ,@xml.value('(//*:status)[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS [Status];
```

Hint: The last one (for *lazy people*) uses the **deep search** (with `//`) and uses a wildcard for the namespace. This is very dangerous if the elements might occur more than once within your XML.

Comment: Is there anyway around using VARCHAR type rather than XML dataType? Please help

Comment: @AdityaPrasad It is a very bad approach to store XML in a string type. If possible, you should change that. If not, you'll have to cast your string. In this case I'd suggest to use the second approach with `.nodes()`, which would need the cast just once.

Comment: Good answer, +1 from my side!

Answer (score 0):

The XML you have is pretty complex. You have multiple namespaces, with different nodes using different ones. This means you need to use `WITH XMLNAMESPACES` to declare all these.

Then you need to use `nodes` to navigate the to needed node, prefixing them with the appropriate namespaces, till you get to `transaction-info`. Then you use use `value` to get the information.

`@Status` isn't what you're after here, that's for is you have something like `<node status=1\>`, you need to get the `text()` value of the node.

This results in the below:

```
DECLARE @X xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope
    xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <SOAP-ENV:Header/>
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <ns:createTransactionResponse
            xmlns:impl="http://traffic2/traffic/services/service1"
            xmlns:ns="http://www.regfrez.com/schemas/service1_V2/SharedResources/XMLSchema/Schema.xsd"
            xmlns:tns="http://www.abc.ae/Activematrix/ESB/service1/1_0">
            <transactionResponse>
                <transaction-info>
                    <registrationId>R1234</registrationId>
                    <trialId>T12345</trialId>
                    <transactionId>12345</transactionId>
                    <transactionDate>27-02-2020:08:47</transactionDate>
                    <status>Confirmed</status>
                </transaction-info>
            </transactionResponse>
        </ns:createTransactionResponse>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>';

WITH XMLNAMESPACES ('http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/' AS [SOAP-ENV],
                    'http://traffic2/traffic/services/service1' AS impl, --YOu don't use this in the XML, but incldued anyway, for completeness
                    'http://www.regfrez.com/schemas/service1_V2/SharedResources/XMLSchema/Schema.xsd' AS ns,
                    'http://www.abc.ae/Activematrix/ESB/service1/1_0' AS tns) --YOu don't use this in the XML, but incldued anyway, for completeness
SELECT ti.value('(status/text())[1]','varchar(10)') AS [Status],
       ti.value('(transactionId/text())[1]','int') AS Trans,
       ti.value('(registrationId/text())[1]','varchar(10)') AS ID
FROM @X.nodes('SOAP-ENV:Envelope/SOAP-ENV:Body/ns:createTransactionResponse/transactionResponse/transaction-info') N(ti);
```